# Software to automatically generate URL Shortcut Apps for various Mobile Platforms

Tags: windows, android, java, ios, windows-phone

I want to automatically generate a Mobile Site Shortcut app to my mobile site for various mobile platforms.

I have a site "MyMobileSite.com" and I want to automatically generate simple native apps that -- when opened in their respective platforms -- will simply open the local browser and take the user to "MyMobileSite.com".

The platforms apps should get generated for are:

- Android
- BlackBerry
- Flash
- iOS
- Java/J2ME
- Nokia WRT
- Palm
- Symbian
- Web OS
- Windows

Is there any **software** that would **generate** these mini-apps automatically?

Requirements:

- The software has to generate automatically apps for all or most of the platforms above
- Any OS/UI/language is acceptable
- Both hosted and on-premises are acceptable too
- Any price is acceptable, but obviously the cheaper the better

---

Getjar.com [used to provide this service](http://blog.getjar.com/developer/app-download-page/):

> If no application exists, GetJar provides a free Mobile Site Shortcut,
>   which is a small application that launches any phone’s native Web
>   browser and redirects it to the appropriate mobile site.

...but no longer does.

Comment: I'd use a simple bookmark, so it can open in the native browser. Why does every website need its own app? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Izzy: Maybe because most mobile users know how to install an app, but only few know how to create a bookmark?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Seriously? How fortunate my keyboard has an airbag for the headcrash... // Oh, besides: "How can I create..."? That doesn't seem to be on-topic here. Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185).

Comment: @Izzy: "How can I *automatically generate* XYZ" is clearly asking for software, thus on-topic. A manual would not be a valid answer, as a manual does not automatically generate anything.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul *How to* is asking for steps to perform, not for software. Though I admit it might be interpreted both ways – and could be re-phrased to "Is there any software that does this". In which case some details are missing: Command-line or GUI? On what OS should that software run – or should it be a web-app? As a web-app, if self-hosted, the environment requirements (PHP? Java? or?) are totally unclear. Guess that's some reasons why there are no answers yet. So as it stands, I'm afraid it's hard to be answered *here*.

Comment: @Izzy: OK, I got bold and fixed all problems in the question.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul too bold I'm afraid. If I read the original post correctly, OP wants to integrate that into the website to "automatically generate a Mobile Site Shortcut". So I doubt that "Any OS/UI/language is acceptable." Better not go that far to fix a question just to have it fixed – if that invokes the danger of making it a different question than intended. If you want that for yourself, better ask a new (precise) question ;) OP hasn't been around here since dropping that question, btw. – so she might no longer be interested, not reacting to our requests.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Yes, I'm still interested in a solution. I'm looking for software that will automatically generate the Mobile Site Shortcut Apps so that I can re-upload them to various App Stores on different mobile platforms. The platform of the software doesn't matter so much as long as it gets the job done.